# How to overwrite django project view/template with apps view/template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm having difficulty understanding the django documentation. I have a django project that has many apps. I would like to create a new app that "overwrites" (not sure that is what I mean) the project app. I'm pretty sure this is a basic concept of django, so I would appreciate links to documentation or clarification.

E.g.

1. There is a template "stuff_tab.html" and a view for that template in the project.
2. In the projects stuff_tab.html template, there is the creation of a table.
3. I want to add a new column to the table using my app, but I don't want to edit the projects stuff_tab.html because it's not my project; I do want to use the code however, so that I'm not rewriting it again and creating a new template.

So basically, there exists a webpage, I want my app to add a single column to an existing table on the webpage, without changing the original webpages template (stuff_tab.html). I'll then need to do something similar to the view, so that I can add my script for what goes into that new column I'm creating.

Does this make sense?

Comment: What is the view function where "stuff_tab.html" is rendered like?

Comment: It's called `template` and not `display`

Comment: From what I understand, you need to write a new view and a new template (like `stuff_tab_extended.html`) for your need. You don't need a new app. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing: i created an identical view in my app view but pointed it to myapp/templates/stuff_tab.html. now any changes I make to myapp/stemplates/stuff_tab.html override project/templates/stuff_tab.html